# Change secondary menu id

Tags: 8, navigation

How can i change the secondary menu id, by default it has the same id like primary menu. My primary menu id is menu-main-navigation and when i print in twig the secondary menu like {{ page.secondary_menu }} it prints with same id.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the id, i am printing the region not the block, just change the block from secondary menu region and will print the new block.